# Which of the following is a Linux representation of a physical USB device?

Tags: linux, devices

I'm trying to figure out which of these could be a physical USB device:

1. /dev/hda
2. /dev/hda1
3. /dev/bin
4. /dev/sda
5. /dev/sda2

What's the difference between `hda` and `sda`? Between `hda` and `hda1`? Which could be USB devices?

Comment: f) we don't do your homework for you

Comment: try tail -f /var/log/syslog  and watch how the entries change when you put or put out the usb stick, maybe the device file to the usb stick will be displayed too.

Comment: casey, if you could just help me.. I've been stuck on this question for a while now.. :/

Comment: What have you tried? What do you think? Can you show us some effort you have made to answer this question for yourself? Have you tried googling?

Comment: One of them doesnt exist, two of them are partitions, two of them are raw devices of which only one of is capable of representing USB mass storage devices.  Why do you think it is (b)?

Comment: HalosGhost, Yes, I've googled. but haven't found anything.

Comment: casey, I think the answer is d. I'm pretty sure from what you said. but I'm still not sure. I guessed

Comment: I'm tied between 1 and 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- /dev/hda1 : No this is a partition
- /dev/bin/ : No this doesn't exist
- /dev/sda2 : No , this again is a partition
- /dev/hdx is used to represenet IDE devices

So the correct answer is....

- **/dev/sda**